# Pharo: Refers to class name instead of "self class"

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I have a simple class `Amount` with the fields `value` and `unit` and corresponding accessors. Now I want to create a class method for constructing amount objects like this:

```
value: aValue unit: anUnit
| amount |
amount := Amount new .
amount value: aValue ; unit: anUnit .
^ amount
```

I get the warning message `Refers to class name instead of "self class"`. How can I improve this? I tried `amount := (self class) new` but then I get the error `A Metaclass should only have one instance!`. (Note that I am very new to Pharo and Smalltalk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Refers to class name instead of "self class"

is a hint, that suggests you use

```
amount := self new.
```

instead of

```
amount := Amount new.
```

As your method is a **class method**, `self` refers to the class.

In a class method, `(self class) new` would (in your example) be the same as `Amount class new`. The class of a class (Amount) is a Metaclass, thus the error message you quoted.

Comment: It seems that the wording of the hint is chosen for an **instance method**. When applied to a **class method** it should be: _Refers to class name instead of "self"_?